# bit-wise and vs left/right shifting

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a 32-bit number where I want to set the last 16 bits to zero. In Python:

```
#a is in base 10
In [143]: a
Out[143]: 536899058
```

Usually, I would do a *bit-wise AND* between the number and a bit-mask.

```
# 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 is 4294901760 in base 10
In [145]: a & 4294901760
Out[145]: 536870912L
```

In this particular case, are there any disadvantages in **shifting** the number to the **right** by 16 bits, and then **shifting** it back to the **left** by 16 positions?

```
In [146]: (a >> 16) << 16
Out[146]: 536870912
```

Comment: I think that `a & 0xFFFF0000` is more clear

Comment: The other way round. First, your're shifting right and then left. Do you have negative numbers?

Comment: Ops, sorry. No, no negative numbers.

Comment: Best to split it over multiple statements for readability, if you're going to use the shifting-technique. Shifting right then left, is something different than shifting left first then right. The intend is not clear here.

Comment: ok, I added the parenthesis

Comment: Negative numbers would still work, even if the right shift is arithmetic (the bits affected by it are thrown away by the left shift). Anyway, why not do the AND? It's pretty clear from the constant that you're throwing away 16 bits, but you could use `a & -(1 << 16)` if you want to emphasize the number of bits.

Comment: Sure, I just wondered if there would be any side effects with the second solution.

Comment: There might be, I don't really know Python. In Java and C#, all those approaches are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from obfuscating your intent and taking more than one instruction, no.

If you want to be 100% sure, feed your query into an SMT solver that can understand bitvectors and binary operators, like Z3. It'll prove whether or not the statements are equal (spoiler: they are); An online repl is [here](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial).

```
x = BitVec('x', 32)

prove(x & 0xFFFF0000 == ((x >> 16) << 16))
```